# How to determine which view is being returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller (`AccountController.cs`) whose final statement of its `Index` method is `return View(model);`.

In global.asax the only route I can see which relates to this is:

```
routes.MapRoute("AccountIndex", "Account/Index", new {controller = "Account", action = "Index"});
```

There is a Views folder, but it appears to only contain partial views and a master.  When I right-click and select "Go To View" I get a "Cannot find view" message, although it seems to do this on all of the controller methods.

So where can I find this view? Where is it located? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely will map to the `Index` partial view, unless `model` is a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

when you don't have view for controller action (for example: Index) you can click right mouse button on "return View();" in controller method to automatically generate view.
by default if you have controller with name "AccountController" and action "Index" the view should be in View\Account\Index.cshtml [if you use razor].